# How to get Overwrite working copy with Repo copy for one file?

Tags: svn

I am trying to get a latest version of a particular file from the repo. SVN UPDATE doesnt overwrite my local working copy.

Actually I have the latest version from the Repository (eg revision 98). After Checkout I made some changes to the file and now I want to get rid of those local changes and get the copy from the repository (which is still at revision 98). How can i do this on Linux machine???

Answer (score 9):

To revert back your changes just do a `svn revert /your/file`

In case you've modified a file and someone else commits changes in the repo SVN will try to merge both versions, if it's not possible it would ask you for help, in any case SVN won't ever revert your changes in an update operation. In this scenario what you'd need to do is to delete the file from your hard drive and perform a `svn update` to get the newest version

Answer (score 0):

Just svn revert ...is the solution.